# mod_rewrite - add middle tier directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

Pages are currently available at the following addresses:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/solutions/article/page-name1
http://www.domain.co.uk/solutions/article/page-name2
http://www.domain.co.uk/solutions/article/page-name3
etc
```

..but I would like them to be accessible via the following addresses in order for enhanced SEO:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/solutions/page-name1
http://www.domain.co.uk/solutions/page-name2
http://www.domain.co.uk/solutions/page-name3
```

So, I think I want to use mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file of the site root to add the 'article' directory after the solutions directory on each incoming page request. I have been looking for a suitable answer for about a month and I've tried learning the mod_rewrite basics tutorials but I just can't make this work for me so apologies for another mod_rewrite question.

This is my .htaccess file at present:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing
    # make it /index.php?/$1 above (add the question mark)      
</IfModule>
```

Comment: For SEO there truly is nothing wrong with /solutions/article/page-name3 and one could easily out rank your SEO urls 10 times over with an url like /?article_id=9566 with awesomely better on page content + page title + good backlinks.

Comment: Thanks, I am however aware of this. The web pages already exist and are live on the web. A new site (on a new platform) was created by a web developer and I am trying to correct the url's so that when it is put live we don't have to implement too many 301 redirects which will usually have an impact on SEO.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar on a site of mine. Here's the .htaccess rules I'm using to remove index.php and show the shortened url:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Removes index.php
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|ico) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/solutions/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /solutions/article/%1 [L]
```

Remember that the URL you see in your browser's address bar is not the URL that ExpressionEngine sees - EE sees {segment_2} as "article".

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :**

Try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^solutions/article/ 
RewriteRule ^solutions/(.*)$ /solutions/article/$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added it to my mod_rewrite code but it doesn't seem to have any impact at all.

Comment: Missing 'RewriteEngine On' maybe?

Comment: I tried the url: http://www.domain.co.uk/solutions/page-name

The content is not there. It is still available on the original address: http://www.domain.co.uk/solutions/article/page-name

Comment: My .htaccess file was so:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`
`RewriteEngine On`
`# Removes index.php`
`RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`
`# If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing`
`# make it /index.php?/$1 above (add the question mark)`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^solutions/article/`
`RewriteRule ^solutions/(.*)$ /solutions/article/$1 [L,QSA]`
`</IfModule>`

Comment: The last tow lines you added conflict with the rule you had before, you must place them before it (place them just after the `RewriteEngine on` line)